# Chartjs and dynamic data arrays

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to add between 1 and 5 data series to chart but having trouble beyond the one data series

So I have my function to create the bare bones chart

```
var mychart
function dochart(id,colors,title,bartype="bar"){
mychart = new Chart(document.getElementById(id), {
    type: bartype,
    data: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: []
    },
    options: {
        legend: { display: false },
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: title
        },
    }
});
}
```

Then my code to create the dataset values (this is just one data series)

```
newDataset = {
    label: [<?=$labels?>],
    data: []
};
newDataset.data.push(<?=$data?>)
```

Now my problem is getting the chart to update

```
mychart.data.datasets.push(newDataset);
mychart.update();
```

But this isn't working - the chart outline is done but nothing else, when I log what is in mychart.data.datasets I can see the data there

```
label: Array(9)
0: "<1"
1: "1-4"
2: "5-14"
3: "15-24"
4: "25-34"
5: "35-44"
6: "45-54"
7: "55-64"
8: "65+"
length: 9
__proto__: Array(0)
data: Array(9)
0: 0
1: 0
2: 0
3: 0
4: 1
5: 1
6: 1
7: 4
8: 57
```

What am I missing here? On some charts I need multiple data series in the dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### issue one: `global` scope:

This is +- your code outline (You run function each time and only changed the original `person` var new object pointer --> This is why your code only creates only one "person" (or chart).

```js
var person;

function hello(){
  person = new Object();
  person.firstName = 'testFirstName';
  person.lastName = 'testLastName';
}

hello();

function hello2(){
  person = new Object();
  person.firstName = 'test_2_FirstName';
  person.lastName = 'test_2_LastName';
}

hello2();

console.log(person.firstName); /*return test_2_FirstName */
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

### Issue two: More than one dataset = array of datasets

Very hard to understand exactly your issue (Please add a minimal reproducible-example).
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Anyway, this is `hello world` most basic example (Add one dataset on click and hide button).

```js
var data = {
  labels: ["Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "America"],
  datasets: [
    {
      /* data */
      label: "Dataset1 (millions)",
      backgroundColor: ["#490A3D", "#BD1550","#E97F02", '#F8CA00'],
      data: [1000,1500,2000, 2200]
    }
  ]
};

var options = {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      stacked: false
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      stacked: false
    }]
  }
};

var myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: options
});

var add_this_dataset_on_click = {
  /* data */
  label: "Dataset2 (millions)",
  backgroundColor: ["purple", "magenta","orange", 'yellow'],
  data: [500,750,1000, 1100]
}

function addData() {
  myChart.data.datasets.push(add_this_dataset_on_click);
  myChart.update();
  document.getElementById("btn").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn" onclick="addData()">Add dataset</button>

<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

- More Complex examples her: https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/
- Related docs: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html

My advice. Start with "hello world" example (Without PHP and dynamic data).

Comment: Your code is using multiple datasets - I want a single dataset with multiple data series like here https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/basic.html

Comment: Ok. "Add data" idea is almost the same (push content to data instead of dataset). This is only a basic outline.